# Image blank when using NSURLConnection but not when using dataWithContentsOfURL

Tags: ios, iphone, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

When I use `NSURLConnection` asynchronously to try and get a `NSData` with my image data in it the image comes back as blank, but when I use `dataWithContentsOfURL` synchronously I have no problems and I get the image data correctly.  Is there any reason why my asynchronous method would be failing?

This works:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
NSLog(@"TEST %@", data);
UIImage *map = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
mapView.image = map;
```

This doesn't:

```
//
//  MapHttpRequest.m
//  GTWeb
//
//  Created by Graphic Technologies on 6/21/11. 
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MapHttpRequest.h"

@implementation MapHttpRequest
@synthesize receivedData;
@synthesize dataString;
@synthesize vc;

- (void)request:(NSString *)url fromView:(UIViewController *) theVC
{
vc = theVC;
// Create the request.
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                      timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);
// create the connection with the request
// and start loading the data
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (theConnection) {
    // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
} else {
    // Inform the user that the connection failed.
}
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse             *)response
{
// This method is called when the server has determined that it
// has enough information to create the NSURLResponse.

// It can be called multiple times, for example in the case of a
// redirect, so each time we reset the data.

// receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
[receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
// Append the new data to receivedData.
// receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
[receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
// release the connection, and the data object
[connection release];
// receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
[receivedData release];

// inform the user
NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
      [error localizedDescription],
      [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
// do something with the data
// receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere

[vc mapImageConnectionFinished:receivedData];

// release the connection, and the data object
[dataString release];
[connection release];
[receivedData release];
}

@end
```

Comment: It would help to see the code where you use `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: @highlycaffeinated I edited it in already, I accidentally hit enter and it posted before I was ready.

Comment: I don't see where you are populating the receivedData object you have created.

Comment: I did find out that the MIME type being returned is text/html even though the url clearly ends with a .jpg.  Is there some reason why the NSURLConnection would be seeing it as text when it's not?

Comment: I converted the receivedData to a String and printed it out and it's: <h1>Bad request</h1>.  Why would NSURLConnection return a bad request when my browser and a dataWithContentsOfUrl both have no problems returning the image using the same url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was giving me a bad request because there was a invisible carriage return or white space.  Trimming it off with:

```
url = [url stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

fixed my problems.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you started looking at the guide on http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html but didnt finish reading it :)

You need to implement the methods that will received infomation about the data being received.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

Its all described in the link i provided.

Comment: No I've implemented all four of the methods necessary for using NSURLConnection, I just posted the snippet with the actual request.  If you think it may be a problem in those then I can post those also.

Comment: Yes please post the full source :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you didn't schedule the connection to run:

```
[connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[connection start];
```

Did you put traces in your delegate's callbacks to make sure they are being called?

Comment: yes I have put traces in my callbacks and everything is being called.  I'm not sure I need to do the scheduleInRunLoop because I'm using the same code elsewhere for asynchronous connections that is working correctly with just text.  It's just the NSData for the image that isn't returning correctly.